# Pass column classic report value to PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-apex

I have page with Classic Report on it (type = PL/SQL Dynamic Content). What I need it's passing one column value to PL/SQL via Dynamic Action when click on another column. It's no problem to initiate click action, but I don't know how to pass equivalent of #col_name# (not :Pxxx_item_name) to PL/SQL.

[image: pass first column value into pl/sql procedure when click on third column]

Application Express 5.0.4.00.12

Comment: Never tried this thing. I suppose, the following should work: create a column with a link, which calls a JS function, which in turn calls [apex.server.process](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-server-namespace.htm#AEAPI29523). You can pass a parameter to the JS function in a link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to pass, so I'm just going to call it "item".

1. In your report add a custom data attribute to the column, `data-item="#COL_NAME#"`. This would go on the image that's getting clicked. You might need to use the HTML Expression option to set this.
2. Create a hidden item, P1_ITEM and set Value Protected to No.
3. Create a Dynamic Action that fires when you click the image in the column.
4. Create a True action on that DA, Action = Set Value, Set Type = Javascript Expression, the JS expression is `this.triggeringElement.dataset[ "item" ]`, Affected Element > Selection Type = Item, Item = P1_ITEM.
5. Create another True action on that same DA, Action = Execute PL/SQL Code, Items to Submit = P1_ITEM, and whatever code you want in the PL/SQL code section. You can reference P1_ITEM in your code with `:P1_ITEM` or `V('P1_ITEM')`.

When the DA fires, it will populate the column value into `P1_ITEM`, then submit that to the server where it's stored in session state, then run your PL/SQL code.